# Spring Tool Suite (STS) 4.8.0 RELEASE - Java disappeared after upgrading from 4.7.2

Tags: java, sts

As per project requirements, I have to run STS on JDK 1.8.
After upgrading Spring Tool Suite to 4.8.0, all Java perspectives, views and preferences are gone.
Is there a way to rollback to 4.7.2?

Here is my ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.800.v20200727-1323.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1300.v20200819-0940
-product
org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/javaw
-vmargs
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:/JavaTools/Endorsed
-javaagent:C:/JavaTools/Endorsed/lombok.jar
-Dlombok.disableConfig=true
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been through the same problem - I'm required to stay on Java 8 too.
I worked around it by downloading the STS based on previous Eclipse 4.16, still compatible with Java 8:

(Edited - the older link pointed to Eclipse 4.17)

https://download.springsource.com/release/STS4/4.8.0.RELEASE/dist/e4.16/spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0.RELEASE-e4.16.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar

Answer (score 2):

Same here! Use this link to download older versions
[STS Archived versions](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Previous-Versions)